# Not seeing custom achievement icon in GameCenter

Tags: ios, game-center

I created an achievement for my app in Game Center with an English localization containing a 1024 x 1024 graphic.

I completed the achievement, but when I load my `GKGameCenterViewController` and tab into the Achievements, I'm seeing the default trophy icon. The English text is there and correct. I am in Sandbox mode.

Why might this be happening?

Comment: Hmm. I'm not seeing the icon on an iOS 6 device (anywhere), but am seeing it on an iOS 5 device (in the GameCenter app). I'm guessing this is a caching issue.

Comment: Note that if it is a caching issue, I have no idea how to clear the cache. I've tried deleting the app, killing GameCenter, rebooting. No dice.

Comment: This is how it works. Sometimes you have to wait a day to see updated achievement icon. There is nothing you can do to speed it up.

Comment: Strange that it goes to different devices at different times -- I'm tempted to think that there is some caching mechanism build in to the VC, but anyway waiting does seem to do the trick.

Comment: It is a problem because it makes development hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think that it's normal for games that are not live yet...
Sometimes happens the same with my game!
Wait some time and then try to look again in the Game Center...

Comment: Wasn't it Guns'n'Roses who said "I've been coding achievements at night, just trying to get it right... all we need is just a little patience"? I might be paraphrasing.

Answer (score 6):

This is a caching issue. To fix it, simply trash the Images folder located at `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<VERSION>/Library/Caches/GameKit/Images`

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do it on device, but at the very least, this allows you to test on the simulator. When the app goes live, it should show up just fine however.